# C# discord bot get member count in my server

Tags: c#

I am studying C# while developing a Discord bot.

How do I get the number of members on my server?

I found SocketGuild.MemberCount:

https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.html

But the SocketGuild *constructor* doesn't exist.

The way I've tried:

```
SocketGuild socketGuild = new SocketGuild(); // impossible.
int temp = socketGuild.MemberCount;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you install the nuget package; what version?

Comment: Have you referenced `Discord.WebSocket`? (I.e. `using Discord.WebSocket`)

Comment: @Caramiriel Yes. v2.1.1

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen It is already in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `SocketGuildChannel` from the `client` object that is connected to the server. From reading the [documentation](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/index.html) then something like this should work:

First connect to the server (snippet taken from [documentation guide](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/getting_started/first-bot.html)):

```
private DiscordSocketClient _client;

public async Task MainAsync()
{
    _client = new DiscordSocketClient();

    _client.Log += Log;

    //  You can assign your bot token to a string, and pass that in to connect.
    //  This is, however, insecure, particularly if you plan to have your code hosted in a public repository.
    var token = "token";

    // Some alternative options would be to keep your token in an Environment Variable or a standalone file.
    // var token = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NameOfYourEnvironmentVariable");
    // var token = File.ReadAllText("token.txt");
    // var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AConfigurationClass>(File.ReadAllText("config.json")).Token;

    await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
    await _client.StartAsync();

    // Block this task until the program is closed.
    await Task.Delay(-1);
}
```

Get the number of members:

```
public int GetGuildMemberCount(SocketChannel channel)
{
    var guild = (channel as SocketGuildChannel)?.Guild;
    return guild?.MemberCount;
}
```

Call it with

```
var channelId = xxxxxx; // The snowflake identifier of the channel (e.g. 381889909113225237).
var channel = _client.GetChannel(channelID);
var memberCount = GetGuildMemberCount(channel);
```

Or you could perhaps use the client directly to get the SocketGuild

```
var guildId = xxxxxx; // The guild snowflake identifier.
var guild = _client.GetGuild(guildId);
var memberCount = guild?.MemberCount;
```

***Disclaimer:*** *Examples above are untested and constructed from my understanding of the documentation.*